# Unhandled JS Exception: _this2.setState is not a function

Tags: react-native

I have an issue with onChangeText in password input. Detail explanation for what i want to do: I want to disable submit button initially and when both input field filled then enable submit button. If you have any other ways to solve this please share.

```
<InputGroup style={styles.inputBox}>
                        <Icon name='ios-person' style={{color: 'white'}}/>
                        <Input placeholder='Email' style={styles.input}
                               placeholderTextColor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
                               value={this.state.username}
                               onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}
                               onChange={this.onInputChange} />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <InputGroup style={styles.inputBox}>
                        <Icon name='ios-unlock' style={{color: 'white'}}/>
                        <Input placeholder='Password' style={styles.input}
                               secureTextEntry={true}
                               placeholderTextColor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
                               value={this.state.password}
                               onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                               onChange={this.onInputChange} />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <Button block bordered success style={styles.submitButton} onPress={this.onSignIn} disabled={this.state.submitButtonFlag}>
                        Sign In
                    </Button>
```

code for onChangeInput:

```
onInputChange() {

  if (this.state.username != null && this.state.password != null) {
    console.log("this.state.submitButtonFlag: ");
    this.setState = {submitButtonFlag: false};
    console.log(this.state.submitButtonFlag);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

1. reference with correct this scope: `onChange={() => this.onInputChange()} />`
2. setState is a function: `this.setState({submitButtonFlag: false});`

Comment: Thanks zvona for your solution, i have made mistake with second point thanks for clearing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your method that you are calling or use callback like **@zvona** mentioned

> First way

1. `onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}`

> Second Way

`onChange={() => this.onInputChange()}`